# Область видимости переменных в Python

Tags: python, переменные, область-видимости

```
filename = "Example.txt"
with open(filename, "r+") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.split()
        if line[1][0].isdigit():
            intf,vlan,*rest = line
        print(intf,vlan)
```

В данном случае будет ошибка что переменные intf, vlan не определены, но если написать так

```
filename = "Example.txt"
with open(filename, "r+") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.split()
        if line[1][0].isdigit():
            intf,vlan,*rest = line
            print(intf,vlan)
```

то ошибки не будет. Почему так? Разве переменные intf, vlan не видны в цикле for? Их область действия ведь больше чем у if. Эти переменные видны в любой области, кроме for. Я читал книги, но именно тут, я логику не ловлю.

Comment: Значит в первом примере не выполняется условие `line[1][0].isdigit()`.

Comment: до тех пор пока не выполнится условие `if line[1][0].isdigit()` - переменных не существует, а в `print(intf,vlan)` вы их пытаетесь использовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filename = "Example.txt"
with open(filename, "r+") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.split()
        if line[1][0].isdigit():
            intf,vlan,*rest = line
        print(intf,vlan)
```

Если не выполнится условие `if line[1][0].isdigit():`, то переменные не будут созданы.
Либо выводите их на экран в условии, либо можно так:

```
filename = "Example.txt"
with open(filename, "r+") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.split()
        intf = vlan = None
        if line[1][0].isdigit():
            intf,vlan,*rest = line
        print(intf,vlan)
```